# Paperclip s3_header proc runs before attachment details set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, paperclip

I am trying to set the `Content-Disposition` of files stored on AWS S3 using Paperclip 5.1.0. docx, xlsx, pptx etc. files are `application/zip` so you need to set the `Content-Disposition` or `Content-Type` to have S3 return a .docx rather than .zip file.

The recommended way is to set `s3_headers` with a proc.

```
has_attached_file :document, 
    :s3_headers => proc { |attachment|
        Rails.logger.debug(attachment.to_json)
        { "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=\"#{attachment.document_file_name}\"" }
    }
```

This seems to run before the file has been processed though;
`{"id":null,"document_file_name":null,"document_content_type":null,"document_file_size":null,"document_updated_at":null,"solution_id":null,"user_id":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}`

How do I get this proc to run after Paperclip has processed enough of the attachment to get basic information like `document_file_name`?

(I have tried `before_document_post_process' and other callbacks with no joy. I also need to store a range of files, not just .docx so hard-coding is not an option.)

Comment: I remember having to work with this some time ago and I plugged into it with the events you are referring to that did not work for you. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#events did you try after_post _process?

Comment: Thanks rii, I just tried it but no luck. I tried `after_document_post_process` with `self.document.options.merge({:s3_headers => {"Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=" + self.document_file_name}})` but AWS S3 console still shows no `Content-Disposition` metadata set. Perhaps a regression in Paperclip.